# Removing the builtin command-line utilities from PATH, zsh

Tags: macos, homebrew, path, zsh

Okay, so I'm a Linux power user, that is I feel most at home when I have access to the command-line, and I'm very much used to using GNU coreutils, so now that I've installed GNU coreutils on Mac OS X using Homebrew, how would I go about removing the builtin coreutils that vanilla Mac OS X comes with?

Please keep in mind that I'm using zsh, so when I set the path to something I do it like this:

```bash
path=(/usr/local/bin ~/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin ~/.nvm/bin ~/bin /bin $path)
```

I want to be able to say,

Include everything present in the current path in the new path, excluding these files: `/usr/bin/ls`, `/usr/bin/grep`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your path to replace the OS X tools with Homebrew Coreutils:

```
$(brew --prefix coreutils)/libexec/gnubin
```

---

Per zsh syntax…

```
path=($(brew --prefix coreutils)/libexec/gnubin $path)
```

Comment: doesn't this just say `brew install everything from now on in 'coreutils'`  That's not really what I want.  I want some that says `include everything in '/usr/bin' EXCEPT for this list of files`

Comment: @AlexejMagura Adding `$(brew --prefix coreutils)/libexec/gnubin` to *your existing path* will mean that any GNU tool will replace the relevant tool found in /usr/bin. If it doesn't exist in GNU's bin, it will use /usr/bin.

Comment: doesn't seem to work.  Adding that to the path doesn't do anything, even if I add it after `$path`.

Comment: @AlexejMagura Adding it after your current path (i.e. $PATH) definitely won't work - it searches in the order given in your $PATH, so the GNU bin must be either the very first entry in $PATH, or at least before any location that you are attempting to override.

Answer (score 5):

First, you don't want to remove the any of the command line tools that apple provides unless you want an unstable / unusable system. However in traditional Unix/Linux fashion you can set up your path statement to check `/usr/local/bin` first, thus utilities installed there (default for homebrew) will be used before `/usr/bin` (or `/bin`). The remaining issue is in shell scripts - you must be explicit since they may ignore your $PATH.